# Creating a pst programmatically from an outlook vsto Addin

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, pst

is it possible to programmatically create a PST file from and outlook vsto Addin as a response to button click with some default values (name, path, etc)?.

I can not find a COM api that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, call [Namespace.AddStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869071.aspx) or [Namespace.AddStoreEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861574.aspx).

Comment: This is to add an existing pst to Outlook right?. I want to create a new pst and then call the AddStore.

Comment: From the link "The path of the .pst file to be added to the profile. If the .pst file does not exist, Microsoft Outlook creates it."

Comment: My bad, sorry. Thanks!